# Is T-SQL's CASE normal ("lazy") evaluation?

Tags: t-sql

Is T-SQL's CASE lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it evaluates the WHENs in order until it finds one that is true, and doesn't evaluate the remaining WHENs.